# which word is better in the sentence?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I'm confusing between "product" and "item"

Which word do you guys think it's better in the below sentence?

**A tool for searching free shipping items on Amazon**

or

**A tool for searching free shipping products on Amazon**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are correct but product is more specific so I would use that. I would write it like "a tool for searching products with free shipping on amazon," or "free-shipping products" because "free shipping" is a single modifier of products, so having them split apart doesn't look right. That's mostly nitpicking though.